# mongodb method without function not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, function

I don't know much Javascript and was making a nodejs app. My mongodb query in nodejs is working only when the query has a function method like `.toArray`

Here's the database.js file

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

const uri = "mongodb+srv://name:pass@clusterurl/metro4?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
// all fields are correctly filled


const client = new MongoClient(uri);

  try {
      // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
      client.connect(err =>{
        if(err) throw err;

        let db = client.db('metro4');

        db.collection('Station').find().toArray(function(err, result){
          if(err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
        });
        
        let a = db.collection('Station').findOne({'_id':4});
        if(a) {
          console.log(a);
        }
        else{
          console.log("No a\n");
        }

        module.exports = db;

      });

  } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
  } finally {
      client.close();
  }
```

when I run the app, the `db.collection('Station').find().toArray` **runs fine** and output the result but the **second query of `findOne` doesn't work**.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findOne` method returns a Promise. You should handle its result in a callback function:

```
db.collection('Station').findOne({ _id: 4 }, function (err, a) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else if (a) {
    console.log(a);
  } else {
    console.log('No a\n');
  }
});
```

Or using `async - await`:

```
client.connect(async (err) => {
    ...

    let a = await db.collection('Station').findOne({ _id: 4 })

    ...
});
```

**EDIT**
To handle the `import - export` problem you should handle the datase connection operations separate `async` functions. 
You may use the connection function to return the database instance:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

const uri = "mongodb+srv://name:pass@clusterurl/metro4?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
// all fields are correctly filled

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect();
        return client.db('metro4');
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

const disconnectDB = () => {
    client.close();
}

module.exports = { connectDB, disconnectDB };
```

Then use these functions to handle your database related operations:

```
const { connectDB, disconnectDB } = require('../database');

const getStations = async () => {
    const db = connectDB();
    if (!db) return;
    try {
        const data = await db.collection('Station').find().toArray();
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    } finally {
        disconnectDB();
    }
}

const getStation = async (id) => {
    const db = connectDB();
    if (!db) return;
    try {
        const data = await db.collection('Station').findOne({ _id: id});
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    } finally {
        disconnectDB();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked fine. But when I did `module.exports = db` and then in some other file `var client = require('../database');`. Now, this same query doesn't work.

Comment: @mr.loop See if the edited answer helps

Comment: Thanks. Although I figured out I was doing module.exports in the wrong place. Removed all try and catch and doing export at end solved the problem